# "Creating" an object in java

Tags: java

Like I have such code:

```
class myobj {
    public static int i;

    public myobj(int _i) {
        i = _i;
    }
}

public class mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myobj a = new myobj(1);
        myobj b = new myobj(2);

        System.out.println(b.i); // Prints 2 - expected
        System.out.println(a.i); // Prints 2 - unexpected
    }
}
```

And I want `a.i` to be 1.

How can I make a 'new' object?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html , look over the material on `static`

Comment: Why is `i` `static`?

Comment: `public static int i` making it the same value. `public int i` would be the appropriate variable.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `static` declaration.  Declaring something as `static` means that it will be shared across *all* instances of a class.  So in your code, both `a` and `b` were using the same `i` variable.  If we just remove the `static` modifier, your code works as expected.

```
class myobj {

    public int i;

    public myobj(int _i) {
        i = _i;
    }
}

public class mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myobj a = new myobj(1);
        myobj b = new myobj(2);

        System.out.println(b.i); // Prints 2 - expected
        System.out.println(a.i); // Prints 2 - unexpected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make this:

```
public static int i;
```

this:

```
public int i;
```

Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've asked change this

```
public static int i;
```

to

```
public int i;
```

Because a static field is shared by all instances of `myobj`.

Answer (score 0):

if you write your class that way

```
public static int i;
```

only one `i` will be created and this i will be shared with all object of  `myobj` ever created.That what `static` key word means and used for. Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) for better understanding. I if want `i` once a  `myobj` created remove the `static` keyword

```
public int i;
```